# Prevent some layers being modified via WFS? - Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

- I have a `workspace` in Geoserver and I have some `layers` on it. I have enabled `Complete WFS` in that worskpace.

Now I want just some specific layers from there **prevented from being edited** via `WFS` because those layers are managed throught a web application and are stored in `PostgreSQL/PostGIS`.

**Is there another way to achieve this without publishing those layers in a new workspace and disabling WFS Service in this new workspace?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the security subsystem to disallow writes on a specific set of layers: 
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/security/layer_level.html
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html